# jenkins ubuntu not accessible if not using port 8080

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I used port 8080 for tomcat, and when I run jenkins service after changing

```
HTTP_PORT=8080
```

to

```
HTTP_PORT=8083
```

(and 9999, 8081)

in `/etc/default/jenkins`, it is not accessible from my browser, but doesn't show any error in terminal.

But, if I changed back the port to 8080 and stop tomcat (that uses port 8080), it works.

How do I change jenkins' port to other than 8080? Thanks!

Jenkins log:

```
 Apr 04, 2016 6:42:06 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:06 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.9
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:10 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:11 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8083
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:11 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:12 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:12 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:12 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:13 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:13 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:18 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:19 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:19 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 11 ms
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 37431
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Apr 04, 2016 6:42:20 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Comment: You are running Jenkins using its own container. You must stop tomcat then start the jenkins service.

Comment: Please check jenkins log in case of any error.

Comment: @Jayan I've added the log above... I can't stop the tomcat since I need it

Comment: Logs "Apr 04, 2016 6:42:11 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8083"  says Jenkins is listening fine.  Please check with "netstat -an|grep 8083".   Then try to connect to the port using "telnet localhost 8083"... Not sure if some kind of firewall blocking access to 8083.

Answer (score 0):

First change port number in `/etc/default/jenkins`.

Then restart Jenkins with `sudo service jenkins restart`.